# Why do Transit Systems in the US Rarely Accept Direct Credit/Debit Card Payments

Tags: usa, buses, payment-cards, payment

In my experience in the US, it is extremely rare to find transit systems (especially buses) that take credit card payments on board. For example, you cannot simply walk onto a bus holding a credit card and pay your fare. Instead (unless you pay with cash), you generally have to load some sort of fare card or app with money, or pay your fare at a ticket machine at a major station. **Why do transit vehicles generally not accept credit/debit card payments on board?**

Comment: Most of these transit systems use EMV contactless, which is only sort of available in the US. Most payment terminals have it, but most cards do not.

Comment: That's true, although apple and android pay (etc) exist, and my guess is if it was as simple as a transit system buying a new kind of card reader that also accepted chips, they would have done it.

Comment: This question, although useful, currently reads like a rant. Please remove the subjective parts to focus on the actual question.

Comment: *many people rarely or never carry cash anymore* — citation needed.  There are other businesses that are cash-only ,and the US is a country of tipping, which is often in cash.

Comment: Do you have any evidence US transit systems are less likely to accept debit/credit card payments than other countries? I've taken buses in Spain, England, Germany, Sweden, Canada, Russia where the situation was similar to the US, except that they do give change.  I suggest you remove the "in the US" part unless you have evidence this is worse in the US than elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Where in the world do banks still issue cards without contactless payments?

Comment: (My favourite system was in Russia, where there was literally a bucket of money standing next to the driver, where people would add their money and take whatever change they needed themselves.)

Comment: To supplement gerrit's point, I have ridden buses in those countries plus several  more, and I don't recall being able to pay with a credit card, which I would have loved.

Comment: @gerrit I would say the vast majority of US credit cards are not contactless.

Comment: @gerrit The USA. Out of the five American Visa/MC cards I have, only two have contactless. Neither was issued by a traditional bank. South Korea has rejected EMV contactless entirely; no one there has it.

Comment: @gerrit It depends on where you are in Russia. In Moscow I never use any cash at all, any payments I make are usually with my phone, sometimes physical cards. In transport you can either pay with a Troika card (in my case it's handled with a special SIM card for extra convenience), or with a banking card. All contactless. Never heard about the bucket next to the driver, he's always behind a glass and you have to talk to him in order to buy a ticket if you don't have one.

Comment: @Malcolm The only Russian bus I've taken was in Inta, Komi Republic, it was 22 ruble for a ride (regardless of destination) and it was unlike any bus I've taken anywhere else. I realise my experience is likely not representative.

Comment: Just a datapoint for the Netherlands: Trains need prepaid card (called OV-chipkaart in NL) to check in and out. Buses, on top of this, accept credit/debit card and have moved towards no physical cash.

Comment: Regarding in-flight payments: https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/credit-card-programs/1662707-how-do-inflight-credit-card-transactions-work.html

Comment: @AlanMunn The recent cards I have gotten have contactless capability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unrelated to the site

Comment: @Fattie can you help explain to me why the question was off topic? In /help/on-topic "public transport" is explicitly listed as one of the topics that is fair game. Furthermore I can't honestly figure out which bullet point on /help/dont-ask I'm violating. Did it have to do with my "attempted worked solution?" I have deleted this in hopes that this was the problem. (Although I'm not exactly sure why). Is there something else? Is it something I can fix? (This question generated two high quality answers that it would be nice to have stick around since Zach and Harper put in a lot of work).

Comment: Also, I note that at https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions it says to "Read the close notice and any comments carefully to address concerns raised there." I can't find the close notice -- where should I look?

Comment: hi @Bunji !   the question has nothing to do with travel.  your question has to do with computer engineering, politics, and economics.   your question happens to mention "trains".  obviously, "trains" relate to "travel", but if I ask "how does a diesel electric invertor work", while that mentions trains it has nothing to do with travel.  very simply this question would be moved to say history or engineering or politics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some bus agencies have done as you propose, including, at one point in the past, [Valley Metro Three in Phoenix](http://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/tcrp/tcrp_rpt_10-c.pdf) (see page 33-34 for an explanation). Those readers have since been removed. A few points:

First, fare collection equipment is expensive, and money spent outfitting buses with credit card readers is money not spent on transportation services. It's not clear that there's a business case that adding credit card readers to buses increases ridership by enough to pay for the equipment. The lifespan of fare collection systems is measured in decades, with many years required for planning, procurement, and rollout, so even if it makes perfect sense now, it may not have made sense in the 2000s, when many modern fare systems were rolled out.

As you noted, credit card fees add up if you're charging once per ride and would constitute a non-trivial proportion of typical transit fares. This is mitigated if most riders charge a larger amount at once, as with stored value cards and daily/weekly/monthly passes. Modern contactless systems use batched transactions and lower negotiated rates to reduce this expense; this was harder to do in the past. Vending machines are not really a good comparison because snacks and soda are high-margin items, while transit agencies seek to be responsible with public funds.

Until recently, most buses were offline. Smart card-based fare collection systems were designed to mitigate this: funds were loaded onto a ([supposedly](https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-21/dc-21-presentations/bughardy-Eagle1753/DEFCON-21-bughardy-Eagle1753-OPT-circumventing-in-MIFARE-ULTRALIGHT-WP-Updated.pdf)) secure card so that the actual transaction on the bus could be processed offline. The card readers on buses would wirelessly send/receive batch data when the buses were in the yard. While it's been done, credit card acceptance without online verification involves a high risk of fraud: anyone that can obtain a magnetic stripe that looks plausible (cancelled card, $0 balance prepaid card, fake card, etc...) can travel for free, and it won't be detected until much later, at which point the cheat is long gone. While any system has the potential for fare evasion, I can imagine transit agencies weren't that interested in one so inherently insecure. With the widespread availability of cellular modems, many buses now carry internet connections for tracking and telemetry (though those systems may be incompatible with fare collection), and fast online transactions are possible.

Consider that many taxis did not accept credit cards when many modern transit smartcards were being rolled out, and those that did had quite slow transaction processing times.

Finally, transit agencies have not always been particularly customer-centric organizations. Thinking like "we should make it as easy as possible for people to pay us money so they'll ride more and pay us more" has not always really been how many agencies operated. Many systems are built for regular daily users, especially commuters and transit-dependent riders, and those people will jump through hoops to pay their fares. That's started to change a little, with some transit agencies appointing [Chief Customer Offices](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bynIYUq6MwT5AdFHpeaT1sRgQ8dDj-ZQH_iWYun_384/htmlview) or similar positions and a growing awareness of the need to prioritize the needs of riders. That's led to initiatives to make transit easier to ride, including easier-to-use fare payment systems, like contactless and fare payment apps.

The modern version of what you propose is contactless payments, which are becoming increasingly common ([London](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/how-to-pay-and-where-to-buy-tickets-and-oyster/pay-as-you-go/contactless-and-mobile-pay-as-you-go), [New York](https://new.mta.info/system_modernization/omny), [Singapore](https://www.smartnation.sg/what-is-smart-nation/initiatives/Transport/contactless-fare-payment-for-public-transport)) along with app-based mobile payments ([Berlin](https://www.bvg.de/en/Tickets/Mobile), [San Francisco](https://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/muni/fares/munimobile), many other cities). This offers much faster speeds than chip readers, works with smart phones and watches, and the equipment is widespread and fairly low cost at this point.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your point about taxis. I've been using credit cards to pay taxis for at least a decade.

Comment: "Modern contactless systems use batched transactions" do you mean batched transactions as in the bus cc system would wait til the end of the day to send all the transactions in one batch? If so, that's a staple of how even non-contactless systems have worked for decades as well. Most of what you say about contactless payment methods is actually true for non-contactless as well. The only benefit of contactless payment methods is that you don't have to pull out or carry a credit card, but can use a smart watch or phone. They're only modestly quicker (maybe up to a second, tops)

Comment: That TCRP report is a fantastic resource. I was unaware that negotiating transaction fees down was already something that was possible, and way to go phoenix! I'm hopeful, so long as cc companies can make contactless more available, and transaction times shorter

Comment: @TylerH I know for a fact that (at least most) non-contactless systems in the US can check on the fly whether your card has been accepted or denied, and the charge usually hits my accounts within an hour (except gas stations for some reason). This evidently was not how the Phoenix system worked.

Comment: @Bunji gas stations will run often run two charges, a pre-auth when and then the final amount based on how much you rang up at the pump. As far as I know, the method POS terminals use to check whether a card is accepted or declined is the exact same regardless of *how* the card's payer data is transmitted. It's much faster because most people are just slow with inserting (or especially with swiping) a card vs tapping because less care and precision are needed. There's nothing special about contactless cards' implementation of tech that is inherently faster *once it reaches the POS terminal*.

Comment: @Barmar My point is that many of the smartcard-based fare systems used by transit agencies are much more than a decade old, especially when you count the years of planning and installation before they became operational. At the time those systems were installed, many taxis either didn't take credit cards, and those that did had slow terminals that would take too long to accommodate a line of people boarding a bus.

Comment: "transit agencies seek to be responsible with public funds."   Only partially sarcastic, citation needed.

Answer (score 8):

There is demand for the service (obviously).
Merchant fees are actually kind of an issue.
Speed is the big factor.
Having people do it while the bus is enroute is unsafe.

### It's about dwell time, mostly

You know that a credit card transaction anywhere else can take a little bit of time.  Now try it with cellular data (often flaky), and a line of people waiting to get on the bus.  You get 4-5 people at a stop all pulling out credit cards, and that bus is now at the stop 2-3 minutes.

It may be holding up traffic if it doesn't have a special pad to pull over into.  But the main issue is that all the passengers are being delayed while you switch cards to one that doesn't say "Declined".

You say "Well, why not do it on the road?" The answer is it's not legal to have passengers queued up in the front of the bus while moving, and the driver can't be distracted by fare-paying complications.

The merchant fees can be prohibitive for small transactions. It's well and good to pay away 3% for overhead, but when it becomes 30-40% of a senior or student fare, that really becomes hard to sell to the board.

### It's also about approval time

The other factor is it is very slow to get payment systems approved and installed on buses.  The speed at which the payment industry is evolving is putting transit agencies in a difficult position.  It may well be that if they were making a cold start *today*, they could implement all sorts of innovative stuff, but there is a lengthy process to get things designed, approved, FUNDED, and rolled out.  And after having done so, they want to sit with that system for awhile and not immediately turn around and do it again because of a bunch of innovations that missed their approval cycle.

The bus systems have rolled out their own electronic pass systems, and they were custom architected to satisfy transit needs, including time of processing, ability to work with no network, and fraud management.  Quite often the passes are free (net of purchased value), e.g. pay $10 for the card at a drugstore and it's preloaded with $10.  So it is as simple as "if you know you'll be using that system, go get one".

Comment: Are cards really much slower than cash? Cash is also pretty slow.

Comment: Debit/Credit card payment on public transport in London, UK, is done using 'contactless' (AKA wave-and-pay). This doesn't require remote authorisation, so the experience is faster than paying by cash (touch the card to reader, about 1 second, beep and green-light for confirmation, customer moves off). 

TFL (Transport for London) also is smart with billing - it will basically store-up all of your transactions for a day and process all of these in a single transaction (i.e. one payment of 4.50, not three of 1.50), thus reducing fees. 

Cash hasn't been accepted on London buses since 2014.

Comment: @user253751 In my experience in the US, most bus systems take cash OR fare cards. Some examples are: MUNI in SF, Metro Transit in the Twin Cities (MN), GoTriangle in the NC Triangle, MBTA in Boston, and King County Metro in Seattle. Cash isn't as slow as you might think, but certainly not as fast as the Clipper, GoTo, GoPass, CharlieCard, and Orca systems on those routes!

Comment: @user253751: you are right. I had to check but my memories were not that accurate. It is true in Argentina that you cannot pay at the bus, but my memory was wrong about a couple more places I checked. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: In Edinburgh, UK the buses started accepting contactless card payments. Typically as fast or faster than cash as far as I can see. You just set your card on the reader things for a few seconds till it beeps and that's it. The speed thing is definitely not an issue.

Comment: @NeilTarrant This is also done as there are various daily caps.

Comment: @user253751 cash is slow on US buses because of the practical nonexistence of $1 and $2 coins, and fares in the $3 range, hence you are stuffing 3 bills into a slot.  (Thank God it simply shows the bill to the driver and doesn't have an automatic dollar bill scanner like a soda machine). But yes, for that very reason, cash is being abolished on many systems, and you either join the club, or walk. That, plus fare inspectors on PoP systems, is doing everything possible to make sure first time riders NEVER return.